# I have a truffle version problem. and I've done it but it's not working

Tags: truffle, solc

I've done `npm install -g solc@0.4.16` and it reads `solc@0.5.16` when doing the `truffle version`

```
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "^0.4.26", // A version or constraint - Ex. "^0.5.0"
                         // Can also be set to "native" to use a native solc
      //docker: <boolean>, // Use a version obtained through docker
      parser: "solcjs",  // Leverages solc-js purely for speedy parsing
      //settings: {
      //  optimizer: {
      //    enabled: <boolean>,
      //    runs: <number>   // Optimize for how many times you intend to run the code
      //  },
      //  evmVersion: <string> // Default: "petersburg"
      // }
    }
  }
```

truble

```
CompileError: /C/Users/imama/Documents/token_sale/contracts/DappToken.sol:1:1: ParserError: Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.5.16+commit.9c3226ce.Emscripten.clang - note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version
pragma solidity ^0.4.26;
^----------------------^
,/C/Users/imama/Documents/token_sale/contracts/DappTokenSale.sol:1:1: ParserError: Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.5.16+commit.9c3226ce.Emscripten.clang - note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version
pragma solidity ^0.4.26;
^----------------------^
,/C/Users/imama/Documents/token_sale/contracts/Migrations.sol:1:1: ParserError: Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.5.16+commit.9c3226ce.Emscripten.clang - note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version
pragma solidity ^0.4.26;
^----------------------^
```

[image]

Comment: Does it work if you comment out `parser: "solcjs"` line?

Answer (score 0):

Truffle now doesn't supports the solidity version below the 0.5.16. So you have to write the smart contracts which are equal or above this version